# How do I use fwrite to write the data 0xf0f0f0f0

Tags: c, binary, fwrite

I need to use fwrite to write a delimiter = 0xf0f0f0f0 to a binary file. It needs to be done in such a way that 0xf0f0f0f0 appears at the beginning of the file when viewed in xxd on UNIX. I'm currently doing it this way,

```
  unsigned int delim[1];
  delim[1] = 0xf0f0f0f0;
  fwrite(delim, 4, 1, destination);
```

But it's clearly not working since xxd is showing this at the beginning of the file:

```
  0000000: 90c9 49ac
```

Comment: You really should learn to compile with all warnings and for debugging (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and to use the debugger (i.e. `gdb`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably should be

```
 unsigned int delimnum = 0xf0f0f0f0;
 fwrite(&delimnum, sizeof(delimnum), 1, destination);
```

Or at least use `delim[0]` since array indexing starts at 0.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
unsigned int delim[1];
```

is an array containing one element.

This:

```
delim[1] = 0xf0f0f0f0;
```

refers to the second element in a single-element array, which is not correct code.

Change `delim[1]` to `delim[0]`, if you want to put something in your single-element array.